# Custom UITableView with UITextview is not scrolling smoothly in ios device

Tags: iphone, uitableview, textview

I  tried to load dynamic images in imageview and text in label ,its working fine in both simulator and ios device. (see below code)

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
      {
          ImageCell  *cell = (ImageCell *)[self.TestTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ImageCell"];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ImageCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (cell == nil)
        {

            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ImageCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }

cell.textlabels.text=@"Cable and Hose Carriers";

cell.ProductsImages.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cool.jpg"];



return cell;
}
```

But if i tried to load a data in uitextview  in the custom tableview cells ,tableview is not scroll smoothly (stutter) in ios device but works fine in simulator.Please advise me to do it better.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
      {
          ImageCell  *cell = (ImageCell *)[self.TestTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ImageCell"];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ImageCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (cell == nil)
        {

            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ImageCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }
cell.ProductsDetailsTextView.delegate = self;
cell.ProductsDetailsTextView.text=[Descriptions objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to do all things ON main thread. Your main thread starts blocking due to dynamic loading of data thats why tableview is not scrolling smoothly. Try to write code in different queue

```
// call background queue for dynamic loading of data
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{


   // load your dynamic data here

    // call main queue here
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     // after loading data in background. use your downloaded data here.  
    });
});
```

Thats It.

Comment: I tried but again  its loose smooth , its happening only for UITextview