# Table view scroll not smooth when large image or content added to it

Tags: ios, afnetworking, xib

I am using table view to show a list of data. Each custom table cell has a back ground image coming from **JSON**. I use **AFNetworking** framework to download those image. *But table view scrolling is not smooth.* I create those cells using `.xib` file.

```
static  NSString *CellIdentifire=@"CellId";
NSMutableDictionary *murDic=[matchListarry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
TTTCellFormatchList *matchListcell;
matchListcell=(TTTCellFormatchList *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifire];
if (matchListcell==nil)
{          
  NSArray *CellNib=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TTTCellFormatchListcontroller" owner:self options:nil];
  matchListcell=(TTTCellFormatchList *)[CellNib objectAtIndex:0];
}
UIView *MainView=(UIView *)[matchListcell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
UIActivityIndicatorView *Spinner=(UIActivityIndicatorView *)[MainView viewWithTag:93];
//Clearing The back Ground
matchListcell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
//Downlod back ground image in block and background thread

NSString *BackgroundImageStgring=[murDic valueForKey:@"MatchImage"];    
UIImageView *BackgrounImage=(UIImageView *)[matchListcell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
NSURLRequest *request_img = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BackgroundImageStgring]];    
AFImageRequestOperation *operation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request_img, imageProcessingBlock:nil, success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) 
{
  if(image!=nil)
  {
    image=[image blurredImageWithRadius:2 iterations:1 tintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [BackgrounImage setImage:image];
    [Spinner stopAnimating];
    [Spinner setHidden:YES];                                                                                               
  }
}
failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"picture.png"] applyLightEffect];
[BackgrounImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"picture.png"]];
NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
}];
[operation start];
```

Comment: You have image data so that use SDWebImage To load image in your table smoothly.

Comment: Search EgoImageView it was very useful for this problem..

Comment: Have you profiled to find the issue? Possibly `blurredImageWithRadius:` but you should check...

Comment: Probably you are downloading the image in main thread, so it is blocking the UIThread, use LAZYLOADING of images

Comment: No image download in background ..

Comment: i think the cell is not reuse

Comment: I create the cell in xib .can you people tell me a write way to reuse a custom cell created by empty xib.

Answer (score 0):

// call background queue for dynamic loading of data

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

// load your dynamic data here

// call main queue here
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
 // after loading data in background. use your downloaded data here.  
});
});
```

[Custom UITableView with UITextview is not scrolling smoothly in ios device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377271/custom-uitableview-with-uitextview-is-not-scrolling-smoothly-in-ios-device/18377787#18377787)